# Frame-ancestors is not working even I give my IP addresses

Tags: asp.net-core, iframe, .net-6.0

I have an ASP.NET Core 6 web site that should be opened in my other website in iframe and I added following code to Startup.cs

```
app.Use(async (context, next) =>
            {
                context.Response.Headers.Add("Content-Security-Policy", "frame-ancestors IP1 
                 IP2;");
                await next();
            });
```

but when I try to open it from IP1 in iframe I get

> Refused to frame 'www.mysite.com/' because an ancestor violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "frame-ancestors IP1 IP2"

Comment: do you mean you put an cshtml content in an iframe?

Comment: No, it is hosted website in iframe

Comment: do you have any tutorial to followed and create your app? sorry it's hard for me to understand your requirement, so I also don't know where to start the troubleshooting...

Comment: No I haven't followed any tutorial. And I can see respose of the website that has Content-Security-Policy:frame-ancestors 'self' IP1 IP2; the problem is I can not open that website in iframe from IP1